# Loop to add extra column works but not when in a function

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a loop that works but not when I try and use it in a function. 
The below shows the data frame before and after the loops

DF

```
  MSU
1  12
2  11
3   6
4   5
5   6
6   6
```

Loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DF)) 
{  
    if(i<4) { DF[ i, 2 ] <- 0} else 
    {
        DF[ i, 2 ] <- ((DF[1,1] + DF[i-1,1] + DF[i-2,1] + DF[i-3,1])/4) 
    }
}
```

DF after loop, an extra column has been added with the average of the last four values unless the number of values was less than four.

```
  MSU    V2
1  12  0.00
2  11  0.00
3   6  0.00
4   5 10.25
5   6  8.50
6   6  7.25
```

Function with Loop

```
myfct <- function(DF){
for (i in 1:nrow(DF)) 
{  
    if(i<4) { DF[ i, 3 ] <- 0} else 
    {
        DF[ i, 3 ] <- ((DF[i,1] + DF[i-1,1] + DF[i-2,1] + DF[i-3,1])/4) 
    }
}
}
```

DF after function with Loop, there should ba an extra column with the same values as column 2 but it is not added. I have used print to show that the loop is being executed and the values are what I expect to put in the 3rd column.

```
  MSU    V2
1  12  0.00
2  11  0.00
3   6  0.00
4   5 10.25
5   6  8.50
6   6  7.25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R passes arguments by value, not by reference. This means that when you pass an object into a function, R creates a local copy of the object. Any changes you make to the object inside the function affect only the local copy, and not the original.

To modify `DF` you need to make your function return the newly modified data frame, and overwrite the old value of `DF` with it.

To do this you add the line `return(DF)` at the end of your function, and then call it with

```
DF <- myfct(DF)
```

which results in

```
> DF
  MSU    V2   V3
1  12  0.00 0.00
2  11  0.00 0.00
3   6  0.00 0.00
4   5 10.25 8.50
5   6  8.50 7.00
6   6  7.25 5.75
```

The reason that the columns `V2` and `V3` are not equal is that there's a bug in your original loop code: you have written `DF[1,1]` where you presumably intended to write `DF[i,1]`.